# About addition on @String

Tags: java, android

I set a strings on my string xml

```
<string name="plus">1</string>
```

I have a textview like this

```
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/plus"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#990000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/pluson" />
```

And I have a button like that

```
            <Button
                android:text="Plus One"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/plus"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:layout_width="280dp" />
```

I want when someone click this "Plus One" button ; my textview show next number everytime. Like 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 etc...

While I try some codes on youtube and found by internet it just stack on "1" or showin "213412412465etc" or just saying some messages like u cant addiction strings etc.

Thanks so much...

Comment: Show us your java code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must get text from your textView, next you must convert this text to int value and add one, score convert to String and set in your textView.

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    TextView myTexView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pluson);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  int value = Integer.valueOf(myTextView.getText().toString());
                  myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(value++));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pluson);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
            textView.setText(val + 1 + "");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Button btn_increase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pluson);
   btn_increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          int num = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
          textView.setText(String.valueOf(num++));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My .xml file:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/plus"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#990000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/pluson" />
    <Button
        android:text="Plus One"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="150dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My class file:

```js
package tr.com.blogspot.etkinlikhavuzu.benimilkogretmenim;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by erisk on 31.01.2017.
 */

public class AA extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.aa);



        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        final TextView myTexView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pluson);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int value = Integer.valueOf(myTexView.getText().toString());
                myTexView.setText(String.valueOf(value++));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My strings file:

```js
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Benim İlk Ögretmenim</string>
    <string name="plus">1</string>
</resources>
```

I want to when someone click "Plus One" button the number on "TextView" addition 1.

Thank you.